# Sharing Files between VM and Host using Virtual PC 2007

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual-pc

I know that I can share files using Shared Folders in Virtual PC, but this method seems to have pretty poor performance. Is there another method to share files that provides better performance? (Besides using something other than Virtual PC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do it is probably set up proper bridge network connection between host machine and VM.

Answer (score 2):

Using VirtualBox, I had problems setting up shared folders (I tried setting it up, and it wasn't working intuitively right away, so I got fed up with it).  Thus, I just ftp'ed to the host OS (which I already had set up since I was on Linux), and transfered the file that way.

I would suggest timing transferring a reasonably sized file via shared folders, and then time it again using FTP... if it's faster, that's your solution :-)

Sorry I can't give actual performance metrics on that!

Comment: FTP is definately faster than say smb. far less overhead in the protocol. I find that if I use FTP for large files on my network i am better off, so I have FTP setup on all my servers facing inwards as well as the regular shares for users.

Comment: Actually i should add though that on linux i find NFS to be very fast performing as well.